Show that $x+x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}$ is not increasing near $x=0$.
This problem is from the question given in my classes: we are asked to show that $h(x)=\frac{x}{2}+x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is not increasing near $0$, which can be proved by the fact that $h$ is $C^1$ on $(0,\infty)$ and $h'(\frac{1}{2n\pi})=-\frac{1}{2}$. By applying this technique, we know that $cx+x^2\sin \frac{1}{x}$ is not increasing near $0$ for any $c<1$ and is increasing near $0$ for any $c>1$.
However, the case $c=1$ somewhat subtle, it can be shown that $1+2x\sin \frac{1}{x}-\cos\frac{1}{x}$ (the derivative of $x+x^2\sin \frac{1}{x}$) has limit inferior $0$ as $x\to 0$ since $$\lim_{n\to \infty} 2x\sin\frac{1}{x}= 0,$$ albeit this does not give us any useful information (at least in my point of view). Therefore, I look forward to any solution to this problem.

I would suggest you consider (carefully) the minima of $f(x)=1+2x\sin\frac1x-\cos\frac1x$ as $x\to 0^+$ and show (e.g., with a Taylor estimate) that the values of $f$ at these points are negative. (You can edit your post with your progress.)

We have
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(x) &= x + x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x} \\
f'(x) &= 1 + 2x\sin \frac{1}{x} - \cos\frac{1}{x} \\
f''(x) &= \frac{(2x^2-1)\sin\frac{1}{x} - 2x\cos\frac{1}{x}}{x^2}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Let $x_n = \frac{1}{2n\pi}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and notice that $f'(x_n) = 0$ for all $n$. However, notice that $f''(x_n) = -\frac{1}{n\pi}<0$. Since $f''$ is continuous for $x\neq 0$, this implies that there exists some neighborhood $I_n$ of $x_n$ and point $y_n\in I_n$ such that $f'(y_n)<0$. We now must show that $y_n\to 0$ and we are done. To see this, define $z_n = \frac{1}{(2n+1)\pi}$ and notice that $f'(z_n)>0$ for all $n$. Therefore $f'$ changes sign between $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$ and we must have at the very least that $y_n \in I_n\subset(x_{n-1},x_{n+1})$, so $y_n\to 0$. We have a sequence $y_n\to 0$ such that $f'(y_n)<0$ for all $n$, therefore $f$ cannot be increasing in any neighborhood of $0$.

One can also argue that $f$is strictly decreasing in intervals $(x_n, x_n + \epsilon_n)$, and therefore not increasing in any neighbourhood of $x=0$.

Yes that works as well and is cleaner.

As an alternative, we can show that $h'(x_n)<0$ eventually for a sequence $x_n \to 0$, for example by
$$x_n= \frac1{2\pi n-\frac1{n^2}}\to 0$$
we have
$$h'(x_n)=1+2x_n\sin \frac{1}{x_n}-\cos\frac{1}{x_n}=1-\frac{2\sin \frac1{n^2}}{2\pi n-\frac1{n^2}}-\cos \frac1{n^2}\sim -\frac{2}{2\pi n^3-1}+\frac1{2n^4}$$
which is eventually negative.

The idea behind this method for $h'(x)$ is to make $1-\cos \frac1x\approx 0$ and the $2x\sin \frac1x$ term negative, therefore we need that $\frac1x$ approaches $2\pi n$ left hand side using something like
$$x_n= \frac1{2\pi n-y_n}\to 0$$
with $y_n \to 0^+$. We can verify that $y_n=\frac1n$ doesn't work in this case while $y_n=\frac1{n^2}$ does the job.

As noticed in the comments by zwim, it is simpler to refer directly to $h(x)$ using for example

$x_{n,1}=\frac1{2\pi n}$
$x_{n,2}= \frac1{2\pi n-\frac1n}>x_{n,1}$

and show that
$$h(x_{n,2})-h(x_{n,1})=-\frac1n-\left(\frac1{2\pi n-\frac1n}\right)^2\sin \frac1n<0$$
noting that in this case also $y_n=\frac1n$ does the job.

Isn't it simpler to just estimate $f(x_n)-f(1/2\pi n)$, to avoid the derivative to be involved at all.

@zwim I started with the idea to work on $f'$ but of course this looks a very good way too! Thanks
